# cli C++ how can I see my user control in toolbox?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I created A project, and in the A project, i created a Form named bform and a user control named cComtermizedCtrl , and i compiled the project successfully ,but I coundn't find the cComtermizedCtrl control in toolbox. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools + Options, Windows Forms Designer, General.  Ensure that the AutoToolboxPopulate setting is True.